# Rocksdb seems to load full Ktable statestore in memory

Tags: apache-kafka, out-of-memory, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

In my kafka stream topology, I join a ktable with a kstream and it keeps crashing because of the memory: the join DSL creates one statestore for the Ktable, and when this statestore is small, the used memory is low , but when the ktable grows with new messages the memory grows too . At some point, the size of the statestore exceeds the memory alloced for the Stream and so it crashes.

**My question is** : with a Ktable/Kstream join, does Rocksdb loads all the content of the statestore in the LRUcache? It seems a weird behavior to me, because only a small part of the ktable is used by the stream at a given point, and Rocksdb is made to flush to disk otherwise it makes no difference with the in memory store.

Thanks for your help

P.S : I already tried to bound the rocksdb memory with the config setter, but it doesn't change much. At some point, it exceeds the size of the configured cache size, or throws an LRUCache limit exception if I enable strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

> with a Ktable/Kstream join, does Rocksdb loads all the content of the statestore in the LRUcache

If you refer to KafkaStreams' caching layer, no. The size of the cache is bound via `statestore.cache.max.bytes` (in older releases `cache.max.bytes.buffering`).

For RocksDB off-heap caches, you can implement a `RocksDBConfigSetter` that you pass via `StreamsConfig` to bound the memory RocksDB uses. Cf https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html#rocksdb

> P.S : I already tried to bound the rocksdb memory with the config setter, but it doesn't change much. At some point, it exceeds the size of the configured cache size, or throws an LRUCache limit exception if I enable strict mode.

So it's indeed about RocksDB? For this case, it seems your `RocksDBConfigSetter` need to be changed. I would recommend to inspect RocksDBs local `LOG` file (a good tool is https://github.com/speedb-io/log-parser) to see where the memory usage goes. It could be related to pinning (eg, `tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true);`) -- if pinning is used it has priority over the memory limit and might violate the limit. For this case, you should disable pinning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I was talking about RocksDb as the heap memory is stable. I disabled the pinning in my RocksDB config class but still the pod is crashing OOM after few hours. I will try log-parser to inspect the Rocksdb content